# Составление рег. выражения php

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения, xpath

Есть HTML разметка:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <span class="btcBalance"><p>N BTC</p></span>
</body>
</html>
```

Мне нужно получить N, при учете, что N может быть числом с плавающей точкой с неогр. кол-вом знаков после точки, опираясь именно на `<span class="btcBalance"`

Answer (score 1):

```
$str = '<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <span class="btcBalance"><p>N BTC</p></span>
</body>
</html>';


preg_match('~<span class="btcBalance"><p>(N|\d+\.?\d+).*</p></span>~i', $str , $a);

echo '<pre>'; var_dump($a[1]); echo '</pre>';
// N
```

Comment: спасибо, дважды выручили))

Comment: @Alexxosipov пожалуйста :)

Answer (score 1):

Вариант с XPath :

```
   $html = '<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <span class="btcBalance"><p>1.2222 BTC</p></span>
    </body>
    </html>';

    $dom = new \DOMDocument;
    $dom->loadHTML($html);
    $finder = new \DomXPath($dom);
    $node = $finder->query("//*[contains(@class, 'btcBalance')]");

    var_dump((float) $node->item(0)->nodeValue);
```